# How to add a value to a RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone show how I would add a value of 0 to the wrong answers and a a value of 1 to the correct one?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    //Question
    lblQuestion1.Text = "Which of the following is not a country in Europe?";

    //Answers
    lstAns1.Items.Add("Enland");
    lstAns1.Items.Add("Germany");
    lstAns1.Items.Add("France");
    lstAns1.Items.Add("Canada");
}
```

Comment: please explain where you want to add value 0 or 1?

Comment: I want to have it all in the Page Load event if that is possible

Comment: your question is not clear. please give some sample output. it will be helpful  to understand about your question.

Comment: I think you want another column  that you store value of `0` and `1` for each item! Do I think correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may add [ListItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of only text.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Question
        lblQuestion1.Text = "Which of the following is not a country in Europe?";

        //Answers
        lstAns1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Enland", "0"));
        lstAns1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Germany", "0"));
        lstAns1.Items.Add(new ListItem("France", "0"));
        lstAns1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Canada", "1"));
    }
}
```

I have added a check if this page is loaded by HTTP Get or by HTTP Post (see: [Page.IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Anyway - this code is completely static.... You may think it over once again.